# For a matrix Lie group when would matrix log and exponential be same as Riemannian log and exponential?

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, lie-groups, riemannian-geometry

Geodesics can be defined on manifolds using Riemannian exponential maps. I am looking for conditions where matrix exponential maps be used to define geodesics on matrix Lie groups.

Answer (score 1):

When the Lie Group is compact and connected, then the Riemannian Exponential coincides with the Lie Exponential, so you can use it to find Geodesics.

This also holds for a Lie Group which admits a biinvariant Metric (which is always
tha case if the Group is compact).

**Edit:** When the Group is compact then you also have to choose a biinvariant metric (but it would not make sense to talk about geodesics without a metric anyways...)

Comment: Is it also possible for non compact lie groups (under certain conditions)? I am assuming that there would be no bi-invariant metric in such cases.